# SetObject took long time to finish

Tags: c++, json, c++11, rapidjson

I have a class that contains simple attribute and I want to convert it to json. The method to generate json is below:

```
std::string Message::GetIncomingMessage(){
        rapidjson::Document d; // Null
        d.SetObject();
        rapidjson::Document::AllocatorType& allocator = d.GetAllocator();
        
        rapidjson::Value from;
        from.SetString(rapidjson::StringRef(this->from.c_str(), this->from.length()));

        rapidjson::Value id;
        id.SetString(rapidjson::StringRef(this->id.c_str(), this->id.length()));

        rapidjson::Value status;
        status.SetInt(this->status);

        rapidjson::Value type;
        type.SetInt(this->type);

        rapidjson::Value body;
        body.SetString(rapidjson::StringRef(this->body.c_str(), this->body.length()));


        d.AddMember("From", from, allocator);
        d.AddMember("ID", id, allocator);
        d.AddMember("Status", status, allocator);
        d.AddMember("Type", type, allocator);
        d.AddMember("Body", body, allocator);
        
        rapidjson::StringBuffer buffer;
        rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
        d.Accept(writer);
        
        return buffer.GetString();
        
    }
```

It works normal but I noticed for the log, sometime this function took around 1 sec to finish.
After check the timing for each function call, the line that took 1 sec is the d.SetObject().

What happened here? Is there any explanation and how to fix this?

Comment: How did you measure the performance in detail? Did you compare debug and release behavior here? What's your runtime context? Is threading involved? From the plain source code of rapidJson, I'd not suspect setObject() to be the real cause of performance dropping here. Something else is going on I suspect.

Comment: I use chrono to take time before and after SetObject and all of function here. The delta time after and before the setObject is almost 1 seconds. My runtime context is in linux, for both x86 (Ubuntu notebook) and in ARM (raspi). Both have the same problem. The application use multithreading but there is no multi thread access so this is exclusively use in single thread.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to mention the triviality, that solely refering to a debugger's line time output is meaningless in doubt. Did you try some 'standalone' tests of this particular usage case/method call, maybe within a separated c++ project/app?

Comment: It is also strange for me so I will still check many things.

Comment: it turns out the whole system freeze, so it is not rapidjson fault